# What is "'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code"?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I want to create a 3-Layer architecture Web application. but finding some issues like:

> An exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>   but was not handled in user code

I have tried `int.Parse()` method even its not working.

How do I handle this issue in ASP.NET 3Layer web application?

```
protected void btnDetails_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int id = int.Parse(txtId.Text);
        Product product = db.GetProducts().Single(x => x.productId == id);
        txtNmae.Text = product.name;
        txtPrice.Text = product.price.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: Whats the value of `txtId.Text` when you get the error?

Comment: it is a TextBox id from where i have to take the value.

Comment: when i click on Details button then exception occured.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `int.TryPrase()` instead of `int.Prase()`.

`int.Parse()` will throw an exception if the input string is not a valid integer, whereas `int.TryPrase()` will return `true/false` depending on whether the conversion is valid.

### int.Parse()

This throws an exception.

```
string text = "abc";
int id = int.Parse(text);
```

but,

### int.TryPrase()

This will return `false`.

```
string text = "abc";
bool result = int.TryParse(text, out int value);
```

---

### Edit

The reason why your program throws an exception is that the text in your `TextBox` is not an integer value. The `int.Parse()` method will convert a string value to int if it's a valid integer value. Therefore, if the `TextBox` contains, for example, some characters like `a`, `b` etc, or even if it's an empty string, then the `Parse()` method cannot convert it to an integer and thus throws an exception complaining that your input string is not in a correct format.

The `int.TryParse()` method goes a step further. It tries to convert the value to an integer, and if successful, returns `true`, and gives you the converted value in int format in the `out` parameter. If it fails to convert because of a problem such as input string being in the wrong format, then it doesn't throw an exception. Instead it will return `false`, and the out parameter will be set to `zero`. This gives you the benefit of not having to catch an exception in the case of input being in the wrong format.

As Bradley pointed out, if you use `int.TryParse()` you should always check the return value. If it's `true` you know your conversion was successful. If it's `false` you know something went wrong. So in case it's `false`, before proceeding to next steps in your program you should do something about your input string not being a valid integer.

Comment: of course; using TryParse can just hide the error and make you wonder why nothing is happening...

Comment: @BradleyDotNET well, yes and no. If you use `TryParse()` you _should_ always check the return value. And that will tell you why nothing is happening.

Comment: Oh I agree, not sure the OP would understand that though :)

Comment: OK I'll add an explanation.

Comment: txtId.text value stored in database as a form of integer and i want to show it in a textbox.

Comment: I think you must read the .NET documentation for the two methods. You don't need to use the `bool` value, the `out int value` parameter in the example I provided for the `TryPrase()` method will contain the int value if conversion is successful. Please read the answer in full and also run the two code samples I've shown. And read documentation.